# Having trouble with a date/time get;set;

Tags: visualforce, button, form, set, get

UPDATE

I made a global string in the controller called temp date composed of the date as yyyy/mm/dd and then used THIS is the get;set; var rather than the one I directly use in the query. When I am about to query with my dateTime var, I do...

myDateTime = date.valueOf(tempDate);

I suppose something was going wrong with formatting (a coworker thinks maybe the display datetime in the default isn't actually what should be passed) and by doing this valueOf, it automatically converts it into what should be used to query

I might mark this as answered with this being a resolution, but I will leave up for a while in case someone can better explain the diff. formats of date/time that are/aren't acceptable and what it was actually doing behind the scenes, in a way. When I set date.today() as the default, the input text would show it in the following format:

and when I do text as yyyy/mm/dd and use the valueOf, what does that actually do? Is there a more direct way I should/could be doing this?

---

This might need more context, but I will do my best to start clear/simple and I am happy to provide more as I go!

I have a field (integer) on my object we'll call myInteger__c and a date/time field we will call myDateTime__c

I have a get;set we'll call theIntVar for that integer.

In apex, I have

```
public PageReference getItemPools(){

}
```

which queries for some records with theIntVar in the query criteria. A VF button calls this and rerenders my display of what the query returns. This function is also used in the constructor for the initial default records before the criteria are set by the user. I have an input field that sets theIntVar to be used, and it all works great when I enter it in and hit the button. Note: there are no issues with this input, button, and get/set vars.

Problem starts with adding one more criteria to the mix with the same logic using the same function, just one extra criteria.

I have dateTimeVar to similarly be used in the query criteria for the date/time field. I set this, by default, in the constructor, to 5 days ago (.addDays(-5) to today()). This is in the constructor and not the called function, so just default.

When I load the page, that input (value set to the "get/set" dateTimeVar) is pre-populated with today - 5 days. Awesome! Better yet, the results are also correctly filtered, so I know that the date var is being used in the query just fine (all happening in that one function).

When I clear out the date field in the input field on the page, and just try to filter by the integer field alone, it rerenders correctly. When I start from the beginning and don't clear it, but alter the date, nothing happens. I mean really nothing - I check the debug, and it doesn't even enter the function at all! But when I blank it out and just use the integer one, it works.

Some details:

The date/time format is "Tue Feb 19 00:00:00 GMT 2019". Earlier in the process, when the function actually works (initial load), debugs show the date format of the custom field and this variable to be the same format, but yyyy-mm-dd

The query is dynamic. Before querying, I send my fields as parameters to

```
public String generateTissueQuery(datetime y, integer x){
   // I have the beginning of a query string that is complete on its own with one criteria, and if y is not null, I add to the query string to use the global vars in the query, same with x. This works, as mentioned, in the intial call:) this is returned in that earlier function and uses Database.query. I can provide more thorough code if needed, but to not start with clutter, I can tell you that this works just fine as per initial load debug.
}
```

This always works for the integer part if the date is cleared and in the debug I can see my query string nicely. It's just when I slightly change the date/time that it, by debug, doesn't even go in the function at all (ie. the button action doesn't happen).

Please ask any clarifying questions, I am happy to clarify anything as needed; I am quite stumped!

Comment: Can you post your actual code instead of words describing your code? Additionally does your VF page have an `<apex:pageMessages />` tag on it that you're also re-rendering with all of the other stuff? (so that you can see errors)

Comment: Hi there! I actually made progress right before leaving work and didn't update this; on the one hand, it seems to have had to do with formatting, but on the other hand, even though it works now, I have no idea why it would have not even gone into the function onclick at all (rather than doing it and erroring). I can update as requested and include my "solution", though my solution doesn't clear up all my confusion so I'm curious as to what the problem was! Will update soon...